# which is a correct flow for MVVM in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm

so far i have observed multiple flows for MVVM design pattern. Not sure which one out of these 2 are correct ?

suppose we want to display weather data in tableview.

flow 1:  (In this flow viewcontroller will never have datamodel objects inside it (not even for display purpose in tableview), whenever viewcontroller wants to communicate it will communicate via viewmodel only)

1. viewcontroller inform related viewmodel to get weather data.
2. viewmodel query API to get weather data.
3. after getting data from API, view model informed viewcontroller about data has been arrived.
4. view controller reload tableview.
5. tableview cell fetch weather info from viewmodel, matching tableview indexpath.

flow 2: (In this flow viewcontroller uses/access datamodel objects to display in tableview)

1. viewcontroller inform related viewmodel to get weather data.
2. viewmodel query API to get weather data.
3. after getting data from API, view model informed viewcontroller about data has been arrived and also send related data with it.
4. view controller reload tableview and display weather data which it got from viewmodel.

Answer (score 1):

In my view, the first flow is better because

ViewModel should keep the data, not the view controller. It will make things simple for you. You should declare your variables e.g. some data array in view model instead of the view controller.

You don't have to send the data to/from the view model/view controllers. Just inform the view controllers via delegate that some data has arrived.

Answer (score -2):

This is my favorite flow :

1 - Create a Singelton called APIManager for handling data fetching.

2 - ViewController requests the data from the APIManager.

3 - Inject the data you've fetched in a view model.

4 - create dataSourceVariable refresh your tableView or collectionView

```
var dataSource: [ViewModel]? {
      didSet {
          (tableView/collectionView).reloadData()
      }
}
```